# How to get difference between 2 dates in number of days,hours,minutes and seconds

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to get the number of days,hours and minutes  between 2 given dates and so far I have tried in 3 different ways but none gives me the correct value.Please let me know how to get number of days,hours and minutes in between 2 given dates.

In all the ways input estdate is Sat Feb 21 12:00:00 IST 2015
**1st way**

```
Date estDate=//date object which returns Sat Feb 21 12:00:00 IST 2015
long estDateInLong=estDate.getTime();
    long currentTimeinLong=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    Long diff=currentTimeinLong-estDateInLong;
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  //gives 6
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60; //gives 21
    long diffHours=diff/(60*60 * 1000) % 60;//gives 26
    long diffDay=diff/(24*60*60 * 1000) % 60;//gives 16
```

which is wrong so I tried the following way again

```
Period p=new Period(new LocalDate(estDate)), new LocalDate(currentDate);
System.out.println(p.getDays());System.out.println(p.getHours());System.out.println(p.getMinutes());
```

**ouput**

```
2
0
0
```

3rd way

```
int delayTimeInDays=Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(estDate), new LocalDate(currentDate).getDays();
    int delayTimeinHours=Hours.hoursBetween(new LocalDate(estDate), new LocalDate(currentDate).getHours();
    int seconds=Seconds.secondsBetween(new LocalDate(estDate), new LocalDate(currentDate)).getSeconds();
```

which gives me 16,384,1382400

which is again wrong.

**expected output**

Current time is 2:48 pm 9th march

from 21 feb,2015 12 noon to 22 feb 12 noon: 1 day

from 22 feb,2015 12 noon to 23 feb 12 noon: 2 day

so till today 12 noon number of days=16

number of hours =2

number of minutes =50

Comment: If your source values are `LocalDate` values, why would you have anything other than days? When would you expect hours and minutes to be non-zero? Your question isn't very clear at the moment... (It's also not clear why you're calling something an `estDate` when it's just a java.util.Date, and therefore doesn't have a timezone...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to get number of days,number of hours and number of minutes between 2 dates.I mean I want to calculate number of days,hours and minutes between Sat Feb 21 12:00:00 IST 2015 and today.Hope you have understood

Comment: LocalDate is just a **date** http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html it has no time.

Comment: Oh, so you mean three entirely independent values? And are you *actually* talking about dates, or date/time values? Because "Sat Feb 21 12:00:00 IST 2015" is a specific point in time, not just a date. If you were asking for the difference between "Feb 21st 2015" and "March 9th 2015" *that* would be asking for a difference between two dates. And once you've got the difference in days, you can just multiply by 24 to get hours or 24*60 to get minutes... That won't take any time zone changes into account, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet he wants "number of days,hours and minutes", so yeah I think he wants date/time.

Comment: @weston: No, it's not clear that the OP wants "days, hours and minutes" as one compound value (in the way you'd have two days, three hours and 10 minutes) - I get the impression the OP wants "2 days" == "48 hours" == "2880 minute". But the question is really unclear at the moment. A concrete example of the *expected* values would be really helpful.

Comment: @JonSkeet source is Sat Feb 21 12:00:00 IST 2015 and current time in india is 9 march 2015 2:46 pm.I want to know how many days,hours and minutes between these

Comment: So, can you tell us what you *expect* the result to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet check my updated question and let me know if you understood or not

Comment: Right, so you're *not* looking for the difference between dates after all, you're interested in dates and times, so you should be using `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`, to start with. Your expected output is *really* hard to understand though. Please make more effort to write clearly - the more clearly you can express your requirements, the easier it will be to help you. You should also provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, with appropriate inputs - something ready for us to compile and run.

Comment: @JonSkeet I gave an example and still its unclear?

Comment: It's still not *nearly* as clear as it could be, in terms of how you get your input, what you want to do about time zones etc. We still don't know why you're using a name of `estDate` for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the OP means `java.time.LocalDate`, not the Joda class. `java.time.LocalDate` is a date-time object.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Look at the tags for the question. And no, `java.time.LocalDate` isn't a date-time object anyway: "A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right this is what you are looking for

```
long estDateInLong=//whatever gives you past date
long currentTimeinLong=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
long diff=(long)(currentTimeinLong-estDateInLong);
long diffDay=diff/(24*60*60 * 1000);
diff=diff-(diffDay*24*60*60 * 1000); //will give you remaining milli seconds relating to hours,minutes and seconds
long diffHours=diff/(60*60 * 1000);
diff=diff-(diffHours*60*60 * 1000); 
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
diff=diff-(diffMinutes*60*1000);
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
diff=diff-(diffSeconds*1000);       
System.out.println(diffDay +"\t"+diffHours+"\t"+diffMinutes+"\t"+diffSeconds);
```

It might be easily done using Joda(may be!) but it can be done this way too

hope this helps!
Good luck

Comment: this is what I wanted,thanks.But I did not understand why you are diff in everysteps

Comment: its because when you have removed number of days from total milliseconds, you now need number of hours above this days which can be corrctly found when `diff` variable contains milliseconds only for hours value